# adding array (list of values) to a json object

Tags: javascript, json

I try to loop through some json (clustered twees from twitter) and count how often particular keywords (hashtags) are present so I can create an ordered list of frequent words. 
this (19)
that (9)
hat (3)

this I've done by creating

```
var hashtags = [];
```

first time I add a new word i add th word and give the value 1

```
hashtags[new_tag] = 1;
```

the next time a find the same worj I just add to the number

```
hashtags[hashtag]+=1;
```

the result is a simple structure with words and values. I can list out what I need with

```
$.each(hashtags, function(i, val){
    console.log(i+ " - "+ val);
})
```

Now I realize I also nee to know what clusters these words where found in. So; I thing I need to add a list (array) to my "hashtags".

I guess what I try to create is a json structure like this:

```
hashtags: {"this": 19, clusters: [1,3,8]},{"that": 9, clusters: [1,2]}
```

How do I add the arrays to the hashtags object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create an object for holding the hashtags:

```
var hashtags = {};
```

Then if an hashtag has never been seen yet, initialize it:

```
hashtags[new_tag] = {
    count: 0,
    clusters: []
};
```

Increment counts:

```
hashtags[new_tag].count += 1;
```

Add cluster:

```
hashtags[new_tag].clusters.push(the_cluster);
```

Comment: Perfect. It now both makes sense to me now, and the code works smoothly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is an Object (`{ }`) for `hashtags` since you are using strings as keys, not an Array (`[ ]`) which you would be appropriate if you were using index as the key.  I'd structure it like this:

```
var hashtags = {
    "this": { count: 19, clusters: [1, 3, 8] },
    "that": { count: 9, clusters: [1, 2] }
};
```

So, when you add a new hash tag, do it like this:

```
hashtags[new_tag] = { count: 1, clusters: [cluster] },
```

And, when you increment a hash tag, do this:

```
hashtags[hashtag].count++;
hashtags[hashtag].clusters.push(cluster);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, your explanation of the difference in notation between object {} and array [] made all the difference in my understanding of this.